# How to be notified when a user with no mutual friends likes your post

Tags: facebook, facebook-notifications

By default, it seems that when a user isn't friends with you on Facebook and you don't have any mutual friends with them, you won't be notified when they like one of your posts.

I learnt this after finding out that someone I'd previously had on my Friends list and interacted with a lot had liked a post of mine, which I only discovered by coincidence when another random user I did have mutuals with also liked the same post.

**Is there any way to make it so that I'm notified when *all* users like my posts, rather than just those who I have mutual friends with?**

Comment: By default you will notified on Facebook for all of the activities happen on your post by anyone. You must be missing something. Please recheck. Test this manually again. Check your Notification settings.